# How to run the code without the GUI

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have a rather long perltk code in my hand and I would like to run the simulation in a batch mode (without using the GUI). e.g. I would like to run it with script like "myprog.pl -b" in stead of setting all the parameters in the GUI and click buttons.

My current method is using a separated XML file for config and the function "after" which means the GUI will pop-out and start the simulation then exit after sometime. It is now working, but I have a question: is there a better way solve this problem? Is that possible to have the GUI shown in the background (so we wont see it) in stead of pop-out?

Comment: You could try `wm withdraw .` to unmap the main window after you start up. Typically Tk apps withdraw the window to build the UI then `raise .` to restore it to view. Better, but more complicated would be to move the core and switch on `package provide Tk` or some no-gui command line option.

Answer (score 3):

- Change the program so it is accessible from both a graphical and command-line interface. Factor out its real functionality into subroutines.
- Run the program in an [xvfb](http://enwp.org/xvfb) so that no window is shown on the main display.
- Configure the window manager to always start instances of this program minimised and/or with a 0x0 size.

Comment: daxim, many thanks for your hints. I like option 3 among these three. But somehow what i tried is not working as expected. Could you or anyone please shed a light? what i have tried 1)"$mw->configure( -width=>0, -height=>0);$mw->resizable( 0, 0 );"  . 2)"$mw->maxsize( 0, 0 ); $mw->resizable( 0, 0 ); Both of 1) and 2) generated a very small mainwindow instead of 0*0. Anything with my settings?  And btw: how do i implement option B with xvfb for perl tk?

Comment: the small mainwindow i got is small enough though, i think i can live with it. Please just help on the xvfb implementation method.

Comment: @complex: Actually, option 1 is the best one. Option 2 is relatively easy to do; xvfb is an external program — it's a display-less X server — so it is possible to set up with just a little tweaking. Option 3 is awful; truly nasty.